# Is it correct to say that a smartphone cable is only a "1A" cable?

Tags: cables, terminology

A store owner said that some lower quality smartphone charging cables are only "1A cables", so if you want 2A, those cables won't do the job.

Is it correct to say a cable is only 1A? Does the metal wire inside of a cable get so thin that it can only support 1 Ampere of current to pass through it? How thin does a cable have to get, before it limits the current that can pass through it to be 1A only? I was thinking the cable is bad only because it has higher resistance than usual (but should be still low, like 50 Ohm?). The current decreases, according to V = IR, because V stays the same but total R has increased due to the cable having additional resistance. So the current decreases, but it might still be 1.8A or 1.7A, not necessarily limited to 1A.

Comment: *"I was thinking the cable is bad only because it has higher resistance than usual (but should be still low, like 50 Ohm?)"* - Please think about this more carefully.  You might be thinking of a [characteristic impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_impedance) instead of a DC resistance.  Consider:  if the cable had a DC resistance of $50\,\Omega$ with $1\,\mathrm{A}$ of current through, the cable would (1) drop $50\,\mathrm{V}$ (!) from the wall-wart to the phone, and (2) dissipate $50\,\mathrm{W}$ (!), i.e., get as hot as a $50\,\mathrm{W}$ incandescent light bulb.

Answer (score 1):

What happens is the thinner cables, having a higher resistance, will drop V=IR volts across the cable run. Which in turn causes the phones charging regulator to drop down to another standard charging level when it sees the voltage at the phone end be much lower than it expects. While USB is supposed to be 5V, phone chargers have been made to be 5.3V or higher on the charger side to make up for the voltage droop across the cable at higher amperage, and newer standards are using higher voltage at lower currents to sidestep these issues as well.

While he's painting the issue with a wide brush (it can only do x amps), in practice the actual current drawn will depend on the specific resistance vs length vs current the specific phone will draw, so he is correct. Cables with thicker wires will allow a higher charge.

Answer (score 0):

The current is really limited by the power supply (the small part that plugs into the wall) , they are usually 1A or 2A.  The 2A is for faster charging.  The cable is not a really an issue for smartphones, the resistance is quite low ( ~ <1ohm)and this is not the issue for smart phones.   Cables are rated for current for example in house wiring, and many other cases where there is a lot more power to worry about.

Comment: so I think what you are saying is that as long as it is a 2A output, then the cable really doesn't matter? While it is possible, I think what the store owner was saying was that a 3m cable or a low grade cable really made the device charge up slowly

Answer (score 0):

There might be some truth to it, depending on the exact gauge of the cables in question.

Assume that the cable is 1m long, copper, and it has a gauge of AWG30 (very fine 0.254mm diameter). This would mean that the total round-trip resistance would be ~0.67Ω, which results on a 0.67V drop at 1A and 1.34V at 2A (and would dissipate 2.7W). This would likely be rather unacceptable, but could still work at lower currents or shorter distances.

The designer would have a tolerance threshold. Let's say that the supply is 5V±0.25V, to satisfy this at 1A with 5V at the source you can tolerate a resistance of no more than 0.125Ω/m which means ~AWG25. But at 2A your resistance cannot exceed 0.0625Ω/m which means ~AWG22.

Practically speaking those limits might be too tight, the power supply can provide a higher source voltage (e.g., 5.25V) or the device can tolerate a lower input voltage at the desired current level, both of which increase the tolerance to cable resistance.

For reference, short-distance Ethernet cable can be anything from AWG26 to AWG22. Other factors come into play such as what are the most common cable configurations in use, which translates into economies of scale.